# Heroku application structure for Django

Tags: django, heroku

I started a Django 1.6 application locally, with the structure that it came with:

```
project
   django_folder
       wsgi.py
   my_app
       views.py
       models.py
       ...
   my_second_app
       views.py
       models.py
       ...
```

Now when I try and deploy on Heroku, it only seems to work with the Procfile in the top directory. I seem to be able to move manage.py around without problems.

My problem is that I have environmental variables set so that in my_app views.py I do the following:

```
from models import my_model
```

When I put it on Heroku, it seems that I need to specify my_app

```
from my_app.models import my_model
```

Is it possible to set an environmental variable in Heroku so I don't need the myapp in front of models? (My second app is not finished, but partly integrated. It is going to be a pain to change all the imports in both apps). When I add my_app in settings.py is this supposed to affect import paths?

Comment: Just curious: what environment variable do you have set on your local machine to do that? Heroku does allow you to set environment variables through `heroku config:set`. See [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Comment: Its in Eclipse, and I shuffled the project structure around a number of times, and changed the variables accordingly. I'll give "heroku config:set" a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need environment variables, just use [relative imports](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports). So in your `views.py`:

```
from .models import MyModel
```

Note the leading dot making this a relative import. In this case there's no need to do anything more. This is the standard pythonic way of doing things.